# Merging Omniauth-Twitter and Devise Email Login for same user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merge, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth

I run a website where I create user accounts and publish posts on behalf them. Now I opened public sign up and I have both Devise email sign up and Omniauth-Twitter sign up. They work fine individually.

However, now I noticed that people signs up via Twitter even though they exists as added by me earlier. How can I merge these accounts?

---

### **Scenario:**

1- As admin, I create a devise user via email (**username: joebutton, email:mywebsite+joebutton@gmail.com** (a little gmail hack here since I dont have joe's email and devise requires email))

2- As admin, I submit posts for the user **joebutton**

3- Later, Joe Button comes and signs up via Twitter with the username of **joe_button**

4- Now there are 2 Joe buttons **joebutton** (added by admin and has posts) and the real **joe_button** signup via Twitter.

**How can I merge this 2 accounts**, so that Joe can login either via email or twitter and access his posts (edit, delete)?

Comment: Right now you may have two different records for a unique person in the users table. How do you know which records belong to the same person? Twitter does not provide the email.

Comment: Hey Pablo, since I handpick the accounts I create, I remember them very well (at least for now) :) Btw, twitter API provides email.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to display all users created by real users. For each one you can select an alias (a user created by you) and call a method to merge them.
Merge them means reassigning posts from your user to the new user, and destroying your user (leaving only users created by real people, with the posts you wrote). If you have more dependencies on the user, this is not enough.

Handle with care :). Backup your database. An error in this code could delete wrong users.

**UsersController**

```
def aliases

  #Users created by real users (twitter omniauth)
  @users = User.where.not("email LIKE ?", "mywebsite%")      

  #Users created by you
  @possible_aliases = User.where("email LIKE ?", "mywebsite%") 

  render 'aliases'
end

def merge
  if params[:id] != params[:second_id]

    # User created by real user (twitter omniauth)
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @user
      @user.merge_with params[:second_id] # Merge with user create by you
    end
  end
  head :ok
end
```

**User Model**

```
def merge_with other_id

  # User created by you
  @other = User.find_by(id: other)
  if @other
    # Assign your posts to this user
    @other.posts.update_all(:user_id => self.id) 
    @other.destroy
  end
end
```

**Aliases View**

```
<h4>Users</h4>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Merge with</th>
  </tr>
  <%= render partial: 'review_user', collection: @users, as: :user %>
</table>
```

**review_user Partial View**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
  <td><%= user.email %></td>
  <td><%= select_tag 'user_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@possible_aliases, "id", "name", 
  user.id), :class => "review_user", prompt: "Select alias",
  :'data-url' => url_for(:controller=>"users", :action=>"merge", :id => user.id)
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript**

```
#This will merge and edit users as you select them. 
#You may want to use a button instead (safer)

$(document).on("change", ".review_user", function() {
  $el = $(this);
  other = $el.val()
  url = $el.data("url");

  $.post (url, { other_id: other }, function(alias) {});
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the codes, trying it now! Btw I just read your Merge description. Thats exactly what I have been doing so far, but manually. I was hoping that with merging, user would be able to use both email login (created by me) and Twitter login (user created). If I delete the email account, user won't be able to use both, right?

Comment: They will only use the user account they created. But the posts you wrote before will be available associated to these new users. It’s not correct to have more than one user record for a unique person. What it’s possible (as I answered in another question you posted some days ago) is to have many logins associated to one user. It’s what I called Identities. You can have many identities (logins associated to Twitter, Facebook, etc), linked to a unique user record.